# Clark's Triangle

Tags: code-golf, math, number

Ok I've been on a bit of a triangle kick recently so here's another one.

Clark's Triangle is a triangle where the leftmost entry of each row is 1 and the rightmost entries are made up of multiples of 6 which increase as the row number increases.  Here's a visualization

```
     1 6
    1 . 12
   1 . . 18
  1 . . . 24
 1 . . . . 30
1 . . . . . 36
```

Just like Pascal's Triangle all other entries are the sum of the numbers to their upper right and upper left.

Here are the first few rows filled in

```
          1   6
        1   7  12
      1   8  19  18
    1   9  27  37  24
  1  10  36  64  61  30
1  11  46  100 125 91  36
```

## Task

Given a row number (starting from the top) and an column number (starting from the first non-zero item on that row) output the value at that particular cell. Both inputs may be either 1 or 0 indexed (you may mix and match if you desire).  Out of the bounds of the triangle is undefined and you may do whatever you wish when queried for these values.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the goal is to minimize the number of bytes in your solution.

[OEIS A046902](http://oeis.org/A046902)

Comment: Can we build a solution with zero in the first row? like in the OEIS sequence

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Since that is out of bounds for the triangle defined here you may do whatever you want.

Answer (score 7):

## [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)), 132 bytes

```pascal
function f(n,k:integer):integer;begin if k=1 then f:=1 else if k>n then f:=6*n else if k<0 then f:=0 else f:=f(n-1,k-1)+f(n-1,k)end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BcoMwDETP@Ct0CybQCZ2m05qm/0JBJgpUZhyafj4VBtM9eNZP9mrH@t7UQ2HHZp5H7zpffwO16BgrBcr@cDORY7Ap570hnrBDr6OpvrAjBrLQX0qYrigPjTgc7hjoJ@/0NeN//nHa@Wml4mRHUeZ9UerjZjVyu9R41F6BiHK4GYjLVdiuEus8EJgLSAUH79A6lSyvtzFs@vU0YXqAg0nfsnNB2Vm39IBnXakkCSG3PYSOZYgRbSmL1gSbLjW0eVk/RizBOtxD54gHjoOA5Xia5z8)

1-indexed.

Comment: Pascal's triangle!

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
[lBB]i:"TTY+]i)
```

First input is 0-based row; second is 1-based column.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzrHySk200opJCRSOzZT8/9/Yy4TAA)

#### Explanation

```
[lBB]   % Push [1 6 6]
i       % Input: row number (0-based)
:"      % Repeat that many times
  TT    %   Push [1 1]
  Y+    %   Convolution, increasing size. This computes the sum of overlapping
        %   pairs, including the endpoints. So for example [1 6 6] becomes
        %   [1 7 12 6], which will later become [1 8 19 18 6], ...
]       % End
i       % Input: column number (1-based)
)       % Use as index. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>22</s> 18 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Martin Ender*

```
X6_]ri{0X$+.+}*ri=
```

Input is `(0-based row) (0-based column)`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P8IsPrYos9ogQkVbT7tWqyjT9v9/AwVDAA)

#### Explanation

```
X6_]  e# Push the list [1 6 6]. This is the first row, but each row will have an extra 6 at
      e# the end, which is out of bounds.
ri    e# Push the first input as an integer.
{     e# The following block calculates the next row given a row on top of the stack:
 0X$+ e#  Copy the top list on the stack and prepend 0.
 .+   e#  Element-wise addition with the list before prepending 0. This adds each element of
      e#  with the one to its left, except the initial 1 gets added to 0 and the final number
      e#  gets added to the out-of-bounds 6. The out-of-bounds 6 is unchanged since one list
      e#  is longer.
}*    e# Run this block (row index) times.
ri=   e# Get the (column index)th item of the final list.
```

Comment: A different technique for getting pairwise sums is to shift one copy left and use `.+`. Normally that has the problem that it retains the trailing element without summing it (which costs bytes to remove), but in this case that actually *saves* bytes because then you don't need to add a `6` on every iteration. You can save even more bytes because shifting left is free if you only prepend the `0` to one copy: `X6_]ri{0X$+.+}*ri=`

Comment: `_0\+` instead of `0X$+` is the same byte count if you prefer.

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh I see, you get an extra 6 at the end of each row that's out of bounds so it doesn't matter. Clever, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 157 bytes

```
using System.Linq;(b,c)=>{var f=new[]{1,6};for(;c>0;c--){int s=f.Length;f=new int[s+1].Select((e,i)=>i<1?1:i==s?f[s-1]+6:f[i-1]+f[i]).ToArray();}return f[b];
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##rZA9a8MwEIZ3/YobJWKbaEiGKHYIhU4pFFLoYDwo6tkVOFIqKSnB@Le7cvpBOjVD3@F0Oj08iFM@VdbhcPTaNLA9@4B7Qa5v2UabN0EIMXKP/iAVwp013ra4PhxarWTQ1nDoCMSoVnoPj842Tu7jjFymY3yIoIKT1S/wILWhbHyGq9wfjVpqExL4LgU0kA90lyiWF91JOqhzg@9l1fFk3ovaOipUMRUqTVkXefB5nW3QNOFVXMhRUvoJr7IttqgCpZjo6NJLvuILned@VZc@5dVkvqhLPTbxqFj2ZNfOyTNloncYjs5AXe4q0Q/i95@/NpE9Ox0wLgppQ6cJTBkTf3L8Ri76@I0@/p@@WQKzkfsBe/JZezJ8AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
a,b=input()
x=[1,6]
exec"x=map(sum,zip([0]+x,x+[6]));"*a
print x[b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1EnyTYzr6C0REOTq8I22lDHLJYrtSI1WanCNjexQKO4NFenKrNAI9ogVrtCp0I72ixWU9NaSSuRq6AoM69EoSI6Kfb/f1MdIwA)

Brute-force approach, calculate the `a`th row, and then print the `b`th number, both inputs are 0-based

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>64</s> <s>60</s> 52 bytes

```python
f=lambda r,c:c<2or c>r and r*6or f(r-1,c-1)+f(r-1,c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYoxDoMwDEX3nsJj3IYhselQUe4SgqJWKgFZLJw@NJIjMfn5v7cd@2fNVEp6/8IyzQHExlcc/CoQR4GQZ5D78/8lI52zsXP4UMSyyTfvJhlnHVqoFzzirc1eZ19nBbp4Uk/NU/UKfAlZQ24ht5BrqNAjlhM)

Recursive solution using 1-indexing. Outputs "True" instead of 1 for the sake of golfing.

---

**Thanks to:**

- @totallyhuman for saving 4 bytes!
- @Rod for saving 8 bytes!

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYpNDoIwEEb3nmKWHSyJ005cGHsYrDSQIJKRjaevxQ4Jq@/nveW7Du/Z55zC1L0ezw7ExhuNCeKd@unTgzTXsiSECP@djLRkI561tIR5kXFeTTJkL2hhS0I87a/T15W3JrgD9oq9Yr/hWvxBY9VYNd41LlpNRsw/ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYoxDoMwDEX3nsJj3YYhjsuAgLsEIUSV1iCUhdMHghwx@fm/t@5xXoRSmrqf/w@jBzGhCS0tG4RewMsI8qrPb3pKZU2oLL4VMa3bV@JprLForguEj7KSrpRXBXdrp9oV7bJW4Ltj7bh0XDrOncIH0wE "Python 2 – Try It Online") replacing the if/else with boolean operators and with a more _flexible_ output

Comment: @Rod, this is a brilliant solution. I'm still trying to wrap my head around why it works. I am still fairly new here (this is only my second answer on the site), so I'm unsure on the protocol: should I include your revision in my answer even though you switched from Python 3 to 2?

Comment: @icosahedron the python version is irrelevent in that case, so you don't have to mind it. generally, switching between python versions to exploit features is considered OK.

Comment: @Uriel thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
n#1=1
n#m|m>n=6*n
n#m=(n-1)#(m-1)+(n-1)#m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0/Z0NaQK085tybXLs/WTCsPxLbVyNM11FTWyAWS2hB27v/cxMw8BVuFgqLMvBKF6GiwFhvdaEM9vTxtw9jYmjwIxzQ29j8A)

Call using `n # m` where `n` is the row number and `m` is the column number, both 1-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s><sup>15</sup></s> 12 bytes

```
!!¡S`JẊ+d166
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm/CoqdH44Y7FZv8VFQ8tDE7werirSzvF0Mzs/38A)

-3 bytes from Dominic Van Essen.

Same method as the MATL answer, except it uses an infinite list of rows of Clark's triangle.

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm/CoqdH44Y7FZv8VFQ8tDE7werirSzvF0Mzs/38A) using ```J``` and recycling the ```d166```...

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
b=Binomial;b[#,#2-1]6+b[#-1,#2]&
```

input

> [row,column]
> [1-indexed,0-indexed]

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>[40](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/213943/1)</s> 36 bytes

*Thanks to Lynn for pointing out the obvious and saving me 4 bytes.*

```hs
n#1=1
n#m|m>n=6*n|q<-n-1=q#(m-1)+q#m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0/Z0NaQK085tybXLs/WTCuvptBGN0/X0LZQWSNX11BTu1A5939uYmaegq1CQVFmXolCdDRYtY1utKGeXp62YWxsTR6EYxob@x8A)

---

Works like [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/130179) but <s>1 byte</s> 5 bytes shorter.

Comment: Hint: You can combine the last two lines into one with guards, and save some bytes.

Comment: @Lynn Gah!  That feels so obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>28</s> 18 bytes

```
{(x{+':x,6}/1 6)y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqOiWlvdqkLHrFbfUMFMs7L2v5q@Rlq0ibVxbJ2ZiXVatDGIZWwOZBlYG8TWGWpy/QcA)

Rows and columns are both 0-indexed. Out of bounds return null.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 75 bytes - Brute-force solution

```scala
n=>k=>2.to(n)./:(Seq(1,6))((s,i)=>1+:s.sliding(2).map(_.sum).toSeq:+6*i)(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY07D4IwFIV3fsWN071CKjAwkJTE0cHJ1cRUKFoeBWk1JoTfXouLcTrJ@c7DlKITbrg2srRwFEqDfFupKwP7cZyDl@igzuGgLfDiT8BpXrS8SJkdUBPb5XiSD0yijAjRRIp4kYS5YaZTldI3TIn1YsQLM8@efMmn8zDbKsKWXLKuJDGxepikKO@o1qM5AIhXon6gWcE4KW2x9j42BCFsznZD5NNf0OlgoWBxHw)

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 88 bytes - Recursive solution

```scala
n=>k=>{def g(m:Int,l:Int):Int=if(m==l)m*6 else if(l<1)1 else g(m-1,l-1)+g(m-1,l)
g(n,k)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BDoIwEETvfMWGU1eB0IsHYkk8evAPvFRosVAKgcaYEL69tkhinMPszrxsdq645m54tKKycOPKgHhbYeoZLuO4RC@uQRZwNRZY@TfAGVZ2rFxqIaEhfeHbRAfHYExJ0jOmsT@cQOhZgC/0mSL9Jn@R0kSnFI/7ilFDTNLh6sCLZnYgNMdMDpPg1ZOo8HmJYFMeqPrBNsBxUsYS6XvSIhwhvtsYcb/YoDZbWjFa3Qc)

Answer (score 2):

## Desmos, <s>118</s> <s>71</s> 55 bytes

Saved a whopping 47 bytes thanks to **@ovs**!

\$f(r,c)=\sum_{k=c-2}^c(6-5*0^{c-k})/k!\prod_{n=r-k+1}^rn\$

```
f(r,c)=\sum_{k=c-2}^c(6-5*0^{c-k})/k!\prod_{n=r-k+1}^rn
```

Both the row and column are 0-indexed.

Comment: This can be expressed quite a bit shorter as a sum. I think this works: `f(r,c)=\sum_{k=0}^2\frac{(6-5*0^k)\prod_{n=0}^{c-1-k}(r-n)}{(c-k)!}`

Comment: @ovs Nice! I was struggling with getting the 1, 6, 6, and didn't think about `0^k`

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 64 bytes

recursive function

rows 1-indexing columns 0-indexing

Output for row=0 and column=0 is 0 like in the OEIS sequence

```php
function f($r,$c){return$c-$r?$c?f($r-=1,$c-1)+f($r,$c):1:$r*6;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUinRUkjWri1JLSovyVJJ1VYrsVZLtQeK6toZAKV1DTW2YKitDK5UiLTPr2v@pyRn5QM1mOiaa1v8B)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 126 bytes

rows 1-indexing columns 0-indexing

Output for row=0 and column=0 is 0 like in the OEIS sequence

```php
for(;$r<=$argv[1];$r++)for($z++,$c=~0;++$c<$z;)$t[+$r][$c]=$c<$r?$c?$t[$r-1][$c-1]+$t[$r-1][$c]:1:$r*6;echo$t[$r-1][$argv[2]];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xDoIwFEV3PqO@gfogEU0YKA2DYXDRxa1piGkqsNDmpXFg4NexsOhwb3LPHY4f/Fo3fvCJJXLUkfWOwjj16dJ298fzdm25SOBF/UcqlrOMlTEXpsX6dpQKoFruryp0HIh8wzAjZmDkchKIYGqYBYegEEgrMFpuiBowTYRAebHR2Pg3dVVUQMdSWDO4H99VZx31B0/jFLooC1ysXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 77 bytes

```r
Reduce(function(x,y)zoo::rollsum(c(0,x,6),2),double(scan()-1),c(1,6))[scan()]
```

Requires the `zoo` library; reads from stdin (the inputs separated by two newlines) and returns the value, with `NA` for out of bounds selections.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pyg1pTQ5VSOtNC@5JDM/T6NCp1KzKj/fyqooPyenuDRXI1nDQKdCx0xTx0hTJyW/NCknVaM4OTFPQ1PXUFMnWcMQKKUZDRGJ/W/IxWX6HwA)

Comment: I know this is >3 years old, but you could save 7 bytes by taking the first input value as 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed, and replacing `double(scan()-1)` with `!1:scan()`.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

```
f=(r,c)=>c?r>c?f(--r,c)+f(r,--c):r*6:1
```

Crashes for negative columns, and returns multiples of six for negative rows or overlarge columns.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 44 bytes

```cs
f=(c,r)=>c<=1?1:c>r?6*r:f(c-1,r-1)+f(c,r-1);
```

Takes column then row, both 1-indexed. Can take row then column by swapping the inputs: `(r,c)`. Will return `row * 6` for coordinates outside the bounds on the right (i.e. `column > row + 1`), and `1` for coordinates outside the bounds on the left (i.e. `column < 1`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
,"’U0¦c/x6,1S
```

A monadic link taking a list of `[row, entry]` (0-indexing for entries, 1-indexing for rows), returning the value.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19H6VHDzFCDQ8uS9SvMdAyD////H22sYxQLAA)**

#### How?

```
,"’U0¦c/x6,1S - Link: list of numbers, [row, entry]
  ’           - decrement     -> [row-1, entry-1]
 "            - zip with:
,             -   pair        -> [[row, row-1], [entry, entry-1]]
     ¦        - sparse application of:
   U          -   upend
    0         - for indexes: 0 -> [[row, row-1], [entry-1, entry]]
       /      - reduce by:
      c       -   choose       -> [(row choose entry-1), (row-1 choose entry)]
         6,1  - 6 paired with 1 = [6,1]
        x     - times        i.e. [a, a, a, a, a, a, a, b]
            S - sum            -> 6*(row choose entry-1) + (row-1 choose entry)
```